# How to exclude .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif from a ClamAV Scan (clamscan)

Tags: linux, centos, clamav

I'm running a clamscan command to scan my users home directories, I'd like to exclude images from the scan as these sites specifically have thousands of images.

Answer (score 12):

```
clamscan --exclude='\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$'
```

- `\\.` is the `.` in the file extension.
- `(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)` matches any of those strings.
- `$` pins the search to the end of the line.

This, therefore, should exclude all files ending in `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.png`, and `.gif`.

Comment: is it case sensitive?

Comment: `Case-Insensitive [i]

Specifying the i modifier causes ClamAV to match all alphabetic hex bytes as case-insensitive. All patterns in ClamAV are case-sensitive by default.`

I always run with `clamscan -ri`  haha, silly me.